# I want to test the button click event update the state or not?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

//people-card.tsx

```
const PeopleCard: React.FC<PeopleListProps> = ({ peoples }) => {
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<number>(8);
    const [btnHide, setBtnHide] = useState<boolean>(false);

const showMoreHandler: React.MouseEventHandler<
    HTMLButtonElement
> = (): void => {
    setShowMore((prevState) => prevState + 8);
    if (showMore === 16) {
        setBtnHide(true);
    }
};

return (
    <>
        <PeopleCards data-testid='ples'>
            {peoples.slice(0, showMore).map((people) => (
                <PeopleList data-testid='people' key={people.login.uuid}>
                    <Avatar src={people.picture.large} alt='people' />
                    <PeopleWrapper>
                        <Title>Name: </Title>
                        <PeopleTitle changeColor={people.name.title}>
                            {people.name.title.length > 4
                                ? people.name.title.slice(0, 4)
                                : people.name.title}
                            . {people.name.first} {people.name.last}
                        </PeopleTitle>
                    </PeopleWrapper>
                    <PeopleDetails>
                        <Title>Email: </Title> {people.email}
                    </PeopleDetails>
                    <PeopleDetails>
                        <Title>City: </Title> {people.location.city}
                    </PeopleDetails>
                </PeopleList>
            ))}
        </PeopleCards>
        <ShowMoreBtn
            onClickHandler={showMoreHandler}
            hide={btnHide}
            label='show more'
        />
    </>
);
```

};

export default PeopleCard;

//showmoreBtn.tsx

```
interface ShowMoreBtnProps {
    onClickHandler: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
    hide: boolean;
    label: string;
}

export const ShowMoreBtn: React.FC<ShowMoreBtnProps> = ({
    onClickHandler,
    hide,
    label,
}) => {
    return (
        <ShMoreBtn data-testid='btn' disabled={hide} onClick={onClickHandler}>
            {label}
        </ShMoreBtn>
    );
};
```

here is my test.

```
it('calls "onClick" prop on button click', () => {
    const { getByRole } = render(
        <ShowMoreBtn hide={false} onClickHandler={onClickHandler} label='abc' />
    );
    fireEvent.click(getByRole('button'));
    expect(onClickHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Here, May be my test is wrong but I want to test when I clicked on button it should update the state showMore with 16 and showmore is equal to 16 then button should be disable. but I can not solve it how to do it. could you please help me?

Comment: If you're only rendering your button in your test, you can't expect a parent's state to update.  Looking at your `ShowMoreBtn` component, about the only thing you could do is test that your `onClickHandler` function was called when you click a button.

Comment: So If I want to test parent`s components state to update. What should I have to do?